# Errors in migration when installing the Laravel Voyager package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

i have i brand new installation of Laravel 5.5, but when i try to install the Voyager admin panel i have this error :

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `translations` add unique `translati
ons_table_name_column_name_foreign_key_locale_unique`(`table_name`,    `column_name`, `foreign_key`, `locale`))
```

**Config**

PHP version : 7.0.10
 MYSQL version : 5.7.14

**CODE UPDATE**

I think i have found the concerned code :

```
        Schema::create('translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('table_name');
        $table->string('column_name');
        $table->integer('foreign_key')->unsigned();
        $table->string('locale');

        $table->text('value');

        $table->unique(['table_name', 'column_name', 'foreign_key', 'locale']); // SOURCE OF THE ERROR ?
    });
```

Comment: can you add this  ` Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` to your app/Providers/AppServiceProvider@boot

Comment: Already done !!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to Update the "config/database.php" for 'mysql'.

> 'engine' => null

To

> 'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',

also Update the "app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php"

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Specified key was too long error, Laravel News post:
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and run these commands in your project folder.

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan voyager:install --with-dummy

Answer (score 0):

The total length of your index is too long.

The column on which the unique index is added shouldn't be such long like VARCHAR columns, because the index will be very bulky and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/1840).

If you do not use the muli-language features from Voyager simply uncomment the line in `*******************_create_translations_table`

```
//  $table->unique(['table_name', 'column_name', 'foreign_key', 'locale']);
```

or try to update your MySql Database to 7.x